# openshift node.js Cannot Get /

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have this simple node.js static file server:

```
var express = require('express');   
var app = express();   
app.use(express.cookieParser());  
app.use(express.bodyParser());  
app.use(express.methodOverride());  
app.use(express.session({ secret: "secret" }));  
app.use(express.static(process.env.OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR + '/public' ));  

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";  
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;  
app.listen(port, ipaddress);
```

When I publish to OpenShift (no errors in the terminal) and navigate to the site, I see **Cannot GET /**

I have `index.html` in my public folder, along with some css and JavaScript.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I figured it out. I neglected to commit the `public` folder. First person to answer and say *hey, did you make sure to commit the public folder?* will get the easiest accepted answer of their life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: Hey, did you make sure to commit the public folder?

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner! :)

Comment: Amazing. Google led me here, and this was also my problem. +1! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need the load the routes.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

You are also not loading any views.

Here's the documentation of express: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: I suppose I should add that this same server code works flawlessly on AppFog (with different env vars obviously). The `express.static` line routes `/` to the public folder, so the routes *are* loaded, and the views are any static content in the public folder.