# openshift, node.js: "Cannot GET /index.html"

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have application on Openshift (Node.js 0.10, MongoDB 2.4)

I have followed instructions here
developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-debian-ubuntu.html
 
and I have modified successfully my app.
When I run it from this URL http://kunsento-mbtest1.rhcloud.com/

it works fine. You can try it.
If I try to use this URL http://kunsento-mbtest1.rhcloud.com/index.html

I get "Cannot GET /index.html"

I get the same error if I try to access any other html file in the subdirectories.

Please could you advice how to solve it?

Thank you

p.s. I have found similar ticket here;

[openshift node.js Cannot Get /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790598/openshift-node-js-cannot-get)

but I do not understand how to apply the solution "did you make sure to commit the public folder?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the `server.js` that comes with the OpenShift's nodejs cartridge, you'll see there that there is the `/` route defined to serve the index file:

```
self.routes['/'] = function(req, res)
{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
};
```

...therefore you will get the index file, when visiting your domain.

Routes are typically created for any other functionality, that should be provided by web applications.

If you'd like to serve static files, you can create a public directory similarly as in [the example you have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790598/openshift-node-js-cannot-get).
Supposing you are using the `server.js` that comes with the nodejs cartridge, you can simply add `self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` into the `initializeServer` function to have the content of the `public` directory served. Here is how the whole block may look like, for clarity:

```
/**
 *  Initialize the server (express) and create the routes and register
 *  the handlers.
 */
self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express.createServer();

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }

    // static files
    self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
};
```

You may also want to look on [this](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for more details.

Comment: Hello Jiri,  
thank you for your advices. I have tried to apply the solution (see here  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B434Tt3wD5AiNGNsclUwVG5wMTQ/view?usp=sharing  
but the message "Cannot GET /public/index.html"  persists.  

url of my Node.js project  
http://nodejs-mbtest1.rhcloud.com/public/index.html

Comment: I think it works, your static file index.html seems to be at http://nodejs-mbtest1.rhcloud.com/index.html. Note that you don't use the directory path (`/public`) when accessing the static files this way. On a side note, you would typically create a few subdirectories inside your `public` directory (like images, js, css, ..) and use it to separate different resources, which can be then relatively accessed under the respective directory.